# Session alternative in CLI mode

Tags: php, command-line-interface

I know that usual PHP sessions don't work as expected in CLI mode because they're based on cookies.

But what if I need to keep some user settings until terminal is closed? For example, user can specify UI language, some extra credentials, color scheme etc. I could save the settings in database but how to associate them with the user?

Is there a unique "session" or "connection" ID at all?

Comment: Maybe this post would help: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/86157/find-out-screen-id

Comment: They advise to use environment variables as a temporary storage. It won't work across all commands

Answer (score 2):

Try dumping the **$_ENV** array to find out which variables are available on your system:

```
php -r 'print_r($_ENV);'
```

Typically you can use **$_ENV['USER']** to get the current user's name for example.

Comment: $_ENV is empty. $_SERVER has some info, but nothing useful

Comment: It could be that $_ENV is not populated due to a setting in PHP. Check that "variables_order" in your php.ini includes E, like "EGPCS".

Answer (score 1):

You can either store some information in the users home directory

```
$path = getenv("HOME") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".myscriptprops";
```

Try it out:

```
php -r 'echo getenv("HOME") . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . ".myscriptprops";'
```

Or use STDIN to request the user to insert data while the script executes:

```
echo "Please enter some value: ";
$value = fgets(STDIN);
```

Comment: Thanks. Each command consists of "php executable-file <some arg> [options]". So each invocation of executable-file will produce a different PHP process. The second approach will work only within a particular command, not whole "session"

Comment: And yes, $_ENV is empty (WIN), so getenv('HOME') won't work too

Comment: Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1894917/how-to-get-the-home-directory-from-a-php-cli-script)